# Why is the structure of votes/answers/views different between some question list pages?

Tags: support

On the [front page](http://stackoverflow.com):
[image: horizontal/separate]

On https://stackoverflow.com/questions:
[image: combined]

Why are those differently structured?

Comment: Does it really matter?

Comment: It does, to me. Unless there is good reason, I avoid inconsistency in my work, so I tend to notice it around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Question lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) typically show the start of the question's texts and the asker's or last editor's avatar:

[image]

The [front page](https://stackoverflow.com/) however, possibly to fit more questions in a page, only shows the title and the asker's or last editor's username:

[image]

There simply isn't enough space on the front page for the vertical arrangement for votes / answers / views.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is showing more questions in the front page, since that page doesn't use a pager, contrary to https://stackoverflow.com/questions.